# alias for cp with arguments

Tags: bash

How do I modify bashrc to include a readme file with the `pwd` to original source every time I use cp or mv?

It should be something like this:

```
alias cp="pwd $1 > readme & cp $1 $2"
```

or

```
alias cp="pwd $1 > readme | cp $1 $2"
```

But instead of the path of the source, it gives me the path of the directory I am in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have aliases with arguments. Since you probably don't have `$1` defined, `pwd $1` just expands to `pwd`.

Also, `pwd` doesn't actualy take any positional arguments. If you want the source to appear in *readme*, use `echo`.

Create a function

```
cp() {
    echo $1 > readme
    /bin/cp $1 $2
}
```

---

Also,

- `&` does not mean ***AND*** – it sends processing to background
- `|` does not mean ***OR*** – it pipes output of left side to input of right side

Comment: this is okay, I carried out `unalias cp` and tried your method, but does not change the result. It's still the `pwd` to current directory.

Comment: @thatgeeman Well that's what `pwd` does. Replace it with `echo` if you want the source in *readme*.